# Simultaneously magnifying on multiple images using magnifying glass in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

In HTML, is it possible to simultaneously zoom in multiple images using magnifier glass? I want to zoom in the same region of 4 images, as I need it for comparison between images. I used the magnifying glass code from this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp

I'll appreciate it if you can give instructions according to this code.

Comment: how is this php related?

Comment: I wrote the codes in php, that's why. Otherwise it is not related to php. But I think it is not changing the concept of the question and its answer.